# catch invalid input in javascript using for loop, if else and prompt

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to understand why my code isn't working. What i want to do is to catch the error when ever the user input a data which is not in my array.

```
 var userPrompt = prompt("Enter which car you like: ");
 var cars = ["Ferrari", "Ford", "Bugatti", "Toyota", "Honda", "Jaguar"];

 for (var x = 0; x < cars.length; x++) {
     console.log(cars[x]);
     if (cars[x] === userPrompt) {
         break;
     } else {
         console.log("err");
         break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It stops right after the very first check...

Comment: How does that happen?

Comment: it always jump to else even my input is correct

Comment: @thinker - Have you seen Christian Landgren or mine answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current logic only one (first) value from array will be compared, and if match not found err will be printed.

The reason it goes in else statement is that, your else statement is in loop and if match not found it will go in else part. This is how if-else works.

Instead try below code. I have added a flag to check whether match is found or not.

```
var userPrompt=prompt("Enter which car you like: ");
var  cars=["Ferrari","Ford","Bugatti","Toyota","Honda","Jaguar"];
var isMatchFound = false;

for(var x=0; x<cars.length; x++) {
  console.log(cars[x]);
  if(cars[x]===userPrompt){
    isMatchFound = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(!isMatchFound)
  console.log("Match not found!");
```

Comment: why does it jump to else? are the brackets not working?

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite the code to this:

```
var userPrompt=prompt("Enter which car you like: ");
var cars=["Ferrari","Ford","Bugatti","Toyota","Honda","Jaguar"];
var x = cars.indexOf(userPrompt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the loop exit the first time it runs. You have `break` inside both `if` and `else`, so if they're equal or no, the loop won't continue.

Try this:

```
console.log(cars.indexOf(userPrompt) != -1);
```

Or if you really want a loop:

```
var found = false;
for (var x=0; x < cars.length; x++) {
    if (cars[x] == userPrompt) {
        console.log("found!");
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found)
    console.log("error!");
```

The logic:

1. I want to know if `userPrompt` is in `cars`.
2. I have to check each element if they matches.
3. For each element from 0 to length of cars - 1 do:
4. Is this car is the same as what the user want?

   - If yes, we found it, we don't need to check other elements, break the loop.
   - If no, we need to check the next element. Do not break the loop here, since I haven't checked the remaining cars and I don't know if they're correct. Repeat step 4 until I've checked all elements.
5. Have I found it?

   - If yes, print "Found!".
   - if no, the user's car is not in the cars list, print "error!".

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have `break` keyword in the else block, which does not allows script to search for the next value in the array if first value in array match fails. Also you have syntax error as you have added invalid braces after `if` block

```
if(cars[x]===userPrompt){
        break;}{ //<-- note the opening brace
```

```js
var userPrompt = prompt("Enter which car you like: ");
var cars = ["Ferrari", "Ford", "Bugatti", "Toyota", "Honda", "Jaguar"];

for (var x = 0; x < cars.length; x++) {
  if (cars[x] === userPrompt) {
    break;
  } //{// syntax error
  else {
    console.log("err");
    //break; //halts further search
  }
}
alert(x === cars.length ? 'No match found !' : 'Match found');
```

Comment: @thinker, can you have just `{` without `}`?. Kindly go through the post once more, you will find that braces are not properly balanced.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the for loop. You can update your code to following

```
if(cars.indexOf(userPrompt) !== -1){    
    // your code
} else {
    console.log("err");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following as loop breaks first time itself it car is not found

```
var userPrompt=prompt("Enter which car you like: ");
var  cars=["Ferrari","Ford","Bugatti","Toyota","Honda","Jaguar"];
var carFound = false;
for(var x=0; x<cars.length; x++){
    console.log(cars[x]);
        if(cars[x]===userPrompt){
            carFound = true;
            break;
         }
    }

   if(!carFound){
     console.log('err');
   }
```